# gcc not giving conflicting types error

Tags: c, gcc

I am making my way through K&R2 and wrote a small program to test the fputs and fgets functions given in section 7.7.  When I compile, I receive error: conflicting types for 'fputs'.  I do not receive the same error for 'fgets'.  From what I understand, fputs and fgets are both in stdio.h, so why am I only getting the error for fputs?

If I rename fputs to fputs_77, there are no compile errors.  Without also renaming fgets, how do I know the call to it (in the getline function) is from the fgets function in my program and not stdio.h?

I compiled with:

gcc -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic -fno-builtin    7.7.c   -o 7.7

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

char *fgets(char *s, int n, FILE *iop);
int fputs(char *s, FILE *iop);
int getline(char *line, int max);

/* demo of functions in 7.7 */
int main(void)
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    while (getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0) {
        fputs(line, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}

/* fgets:  get at most n chars from iop */
char *fgets(char *s, int n, FILE *iop)
{
    register int c;
    register char *cs;

    cs = s;
    while (--n > 0 && (c = getc(iop)) != EOF) {
        if ((*cs++ = c) == '\n') {
            break;
        }
    }
    *cs = '\0';
    return (c == EOF && cs == s) ? NULL : s;
}

/* fputs:  put string s on file iop */
int fputs(char *s, FILE *iop)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = *s++)) {    /* assignment */
        putc(c, iop);
    }
    return ferror(iop) ? EOF : 0;
}

/* getline:  read a line, return length */
int getline(char *line, int max)
{
    if (fgets(line, max, stdin) == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return strlen(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, by the way, that despite my geek reverence for Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie, I have to observe that even the second edition of K&R is now pretty dated.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thanks for the answer!  And ya, I realize K&R is dated, but I'm glad I'm reading it, appreciating it's historical importance.  I think without the internet (read: finding helpful people like you on sites like stackoverflow), it would be more challenging to get through.

Comment: Note: K&R2 is outdated since 18 years and does not cover modern standard C. Get a more recent C book.

Comment: Re-declaring standard functions invokes undefined behaviour. That's one of the problem using outdated books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you are permitted to declare functions (and variables) multiple times, provided that all the declarations are *compatible*.  You declare `fgets()` compatibly with (in fact identically to) the standard library's declaration of the same function in stdio.h, and your compiler has no problem with that.  The same is not true for your `fputs()`.

You declare that function as

```
int fputs(char *s, FILE *iop);
```

, but in C99, the C standard library declares it as

```
int fputs(const char *s, FILE *iop);
```

, and in C11, the C standard library declares it as

```
int fputs(const char * restrict s, FILE *iop);
```

.  Either way, the extra qualifiers on the function's first parameter make the standard library's declaration incompatible with yours, and that's what the compiler's complaining about.

Inasmuch as your compiler is accepting compatible redeclarations and redefinitions of standard library functions, you have two possible fixes:

1. change your declarations to match the standard library's, or
2. avoid including stdio.h, either directly or indirectly.

On the other hand, notwithstanding any of the above, be aware that redeclaring or redefining the identifier of a standard library function as an external function, as you are doing, produces undefined behavior per [paragraph 7.1.3/2 of the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3p2).  As such, the compiler is not obligated to accept it even if your declarations are identical, and the runtime behavior can be anything, as far as C is concerned.  Far and away your ***best*** alternative is to give your functions names that do not collide with the standard library.

Comment: As I read the standard, it is explicitly forbidden to (re)declare an identifier of the standard library (see 7.1.3). There might be implementation-specific attributes, pragmas, etc. in the standard header.

Comment: @Olaf, I have revised my comments in light of 7.1.3.  I observe, however, that C does not in any way *forbid* redeclaration of the identifiers of standard library functions; rather, it specifies that behavior is undefined (as far as it is concerned) if you do so.  This is still an excellent reason to avoid the practice, which I now recommend.

Comment: Well, yes the standard hardly _forbids_ something, but makes it invoke undefined behaviour. While some kinds of _undefined behaviour_ can be very well defined by an implementation, thus be safe to use (e.g. convertion a function pointer to `void *`), this should be always avoided. That's what I meant with "forbidden". (the actual phrasing says the names are _reserved_, which can be very well interpreted as "do not (re)declare".)

Comment: @Olaf, I'd accept "forbid" as a reasonable term for describing the standard's various "shall not" requirements, and maybe for describing the converse of any of its "shall" requirements.  There are more than a few of these, and they have a stronger flavor to me (albeit not a stronger actual effect) than provisions that simply make constructs or actions have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Because `fgets()`'s declration/definition doesn't conflict with the standard function's declaration in `<stdio.h>` and you are allowed to
have multiple external declarations as long as they're compatible.

But `fputs()`'s declaration differs with the standard one provided in `<stdio.h>`.

NB: Your program is not strictly conforming to the C standard since you are re-defining standard functions. You are better off renaming your functions to something else - such as `my_fgets()`, `my_fputs()` etc.

While `getline()` is not in C standard, it' in POSIX standard. So, you may want to rename it too. `-ansi` is equivalent to `-std=c90` - if you ever happen to compile under POSIX, this might get in the way. You could rename this to `my_getline()` as well.

> Without also renaming fgets, how do I know the call to it (in the getline function) is from the fgets function in my program and not stdio.h?

The usual symbol resolving order done by GNU linker is that the symbols within your programs come first. That means if you provide a compatible declaration (that gets past compiler diagnostics) then you can be sure it's *your* `fgets()` that's called. You can easily test this with `printf()` statements in your functions for example.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  After reading John Bollinger's answer, I did exactly as you suggested, tested with a printf() statement.